# checkboxes matrix with MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I need to disply a matrix of checkboxes like the one in here
[asp.net mvc checkbox/radiobutton matrix model-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391055/asp-net-mvc-checkbox-radiobutton-matrix-model-binding)

well, instead of subquestions I haves roles and types, so here is my code:

my models:

```
public class role
{
    public role()
    {
        types = new List<role_type>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int role_id { get; set; }
    public string role_name { get; set; }
    public int role_value { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsSelected { get; set; }

    public IList<role_type> types { get; set; }
}

public class role_type
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

My view Model:

```
public class roleViewModel
{
    public roleViewModel()
    {
        Roles = new List<role>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public IList<role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
public class roleviewmodelController : Controller
{
    private Context db = new Context();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(roleViewModel rvm)
    {
        return View(rvm);
    }
}
```

and my view

```
@model UsersManagement.Models.roleViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Roles.Count(); i++)
{
  <div id="roles">            
    <ul>
      @for (var j = 0; j <4; j++)
      {
        <li>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>Model.Roles[i].types[j].IsSelected)</li>
      }
    </ul>  
  </div>
 }
```

this doesn't display anything, what am i missing?

the types should be like (Edit, Delete, Read, Create) and the roles like: manage companies, manage invoices, etc...

PS: My final goal is to customise the authorization system but this is another issue.

Comment: First remove the `roleViewModel rvm` parameter from your GET method and initialize a new instance, then return that instance (your model contains complex objects and collections so they will all be `null` or empty after binding)

Comment: thank you !  but even after that i still got nothing.

Comment: Apart from `Model.Roles.Count()` being zero, even if it did contain items, your only ever rending just a checkbox (no headings or labels) so view wouldn't make mauch sense

Comment: Have you added some `role`s` and `role_type`'s to the model?

Comment: i'm binding from a database which contains some role's and role_type's of course.

Comment: Where are you binding? All you have is a new instance of `roleViewModel` with an empty list of roles. You haven't populate the properties. And I will roll back you change (dont edit the question with corrected code - the comments and answers wont make any sense)

Comment: Okey. what I meant is that i'm using a databse for storing data. and a context to retrive data from database.

Comment: You haven't given enough information to comment on your database code or structure, but your GET method should probably have parameter `int ID`, then based on the ID, get the data from the database and populate your view model. I suggest you just hard code in some values to test that the view does in fact render the checkboxes. Bbut as I noted above - you don't render any headings for the role, or labels for the checkboxes, or any inputs for the `role` or `role_type` ID's so it wouldn't make much sense when you post back.